# checking column entry

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/730I1.png)

I'm trying to verify if the row has an Arrival Date then my function should do the calculation, else do nothing.
 As you can see in the picture, the first row has all values and the LOS time is correct, but the other rows doesn't have values and the LOS should be empty.

Here is my Model code:

```
function time_ago($ptime) {

    $query = null; //emptying in case 
    $shift_id   = $_POST['shift_id'];
    $arrival_time = $_POST['arrival_time'];
    $query = $this->db->get_where('shift', array('shift_id' => $shift_id));
    $count = $query->num_rows(); //counting result from query       

    if ($count = 0) {

    $today = time();
    $createdday = strtotime($ptime); //mysql timestamp of when post was created 

    $datediff = abs($today - $createdday);
    $difftext = "";
    $years = floor($datediff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $months = floor(($datediff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $days = floor(($datediff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));
    $hours = floor($datediff / 3600);
    $minutes = floor($datediff / 60);
    $seconds = floor($datediff);
    //year checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($years > 1)
            $difftext = $years . " years";
        elseif ($years == 1)
            $difftext = $years . " year";
    }
    //month checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($months > 1)
            $difftext = $months . " months";
        elseif ($months == 1)
            $difftext = $months . " month";
    }
    //month checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($days > 1)
            $difftext = $days . " days";
        elseif ($days == 1)
            $difftext = $days . " day";
    }
    //hour checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($hours > 1)
            $difftext = $hours . " hours";
        elseif ($hours == 1)
            $difftext = $hours . " hour";
    }
    //minutes checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($minutes > 1)
            $difftext = $minutes . " minutes";
        elseif ($minutes == 1)
            $difftext = $minutes . " minute";
    }
    //seconds checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($seconds > 1)
            $difftext = $seconds . " seconds";
        elseif ($seconds == 1)
            $difftext = $seconds . " second";
    }
    return $difftext;
}else{
return null; 
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a new condition to the function instead of SQL checking
your function will look like this:

```
    function time_ago($ptime) {
    $today = time();
    $createdday = strtotime($ptime); //mysql timestamp of when post was created     
    $datediff = abs($today - $createdday);
    $difftext = "";
    $years = floor($datediff / (365 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $months = floor(($datediff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (30 * 60 * 60 * 24));
    $days = floor(($datediff - $years * 365 * 60 * 60 * 24 - $months * 30 * 60 * 60 * 24) / (60 * 60 * 24));
    $hours = floor($datediff / 3600);
    $minutes = floor($datediff / 60);
    $seconds = floor($datediff);
    //year checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($years > 1)
            $difftext = $years . " years";
        elseif ($years == 1)
            $difftext = $years . " year";
    }
    //month checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($months > 1)
            $difftext = $months . " months";
        elseif ($months == 1)
            $difftext = $months . " month";
    }
    //month checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($days > 1)
            $difftext = $days . " days";
        elseif ($days == 1)
            $difftext = $days . " day";
    }
    //hour checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($hours > 1)
            $difftext = $hours . " hours";
        elseif ($hours == 1)
            $difftext = $hours . " hour";
    }
    //minutes checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($minutes > 1)
            $difftext = $minutes . " minutes";
        elseif ($minutes == 1)
            $difftext = $minutes . " minute";
    }
    //seconds checker  
    if ($difftext == "") {
        if ($seconds > 1)
            $difftext = $seconds . " seconds";
        elseif ($seconds == 1)
            $difftext = $seconds . " second";
    }
    if ($difftext == "49 years") {
            $difftext = "";
    }
    return $difftext;
}
```